# Converting non standard date using datenum

Tags: matlab, datetime, time, cell

I am trying to use `datenum` to get a datenumber for a set of dates from a cell. Automatic `datenum` works but it only gets times correctly using conversion, and not days.

The date format is like this: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000`

And I have tried using

```
X_time(:,1) = datenum(Y_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')
```

to no avail:

```
Error using datenum (line 178)
DATENUM failed.
```

Caused by:

```
Error using dtstr2dtnummx
Failed on converting date string to date number.
```

Comment: Please display what `Ytime` looks like.  The date format you have specified in comparison to the desired format in `datenum` do not agree.

Comment: I can't paste a picture in this kind of reply, but looks like what I have mentioned:  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000

Comment: Then your line of code needs to change to: `X_time(:,1) = datenum(Ytime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF');`.  `Y_time` needs to agree with your formatting string (second parameter to `datenum`).

Comment: I also tried 'yyyy/mm/dd' of course but it didn't work.

Comment: Please re-read my comment to you above.  Try that line of code and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng, it's not recognizing this format either:

Error using datenum (line 178)
DATENUM failed.


Caused by:
    Error using cnv2icudf (line 131)
    Unrecognized minute format.  Format string: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF.

Comment: My mistake, I capitalized the years, months and days in the format string when I didn't have to.... I should have known that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string for `datenum` must exactly match the format of the string you're inputting, and no field can be specified more than once. When defining `datenum` format strings, it is therefore important to differentiate between `MM` (minutes) and `mm` (month).

So `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000` becomes `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF`

While months and minutes are the only ones that have this overlap problem, it is standard to use lower case for dates and upper case for times in the format string.

Comment: Doh! Typo from my comment in the post above. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: Interesting to learn this but regrettably now i get
    Error using dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.

Comment: I think you need to check what "Y_time" contains.  I tried it on a string that contains the format you stated in your post and it works fine.  Possibly one part of your cell array is empty, has a different format/content, etc.

Comment: It turned out okayish because Matlab too the liberty of formatting the times to dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS in the workspace without telling me.